# Rabbitmq connection via domain name instead of IP

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

I am using Rabbitmq, and i would like to connect to rabbitmq server via domain name instead of IP.
is there any way?
thank you.

Comment: Have you found an answer?

Answer (score 0):

But if you have the domain name, you can always obtain the IP address.

Comment: i edited the question , as the reason behind it is ambiguous , but the important thing is how to achieve  it .